# Areas within Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Is it possible to have Areas within areas?

Like let say you have a area forum and you want to have admin area forum also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have Areas within areas?

No. But you can have controllers inside those areas. They won't provide you the same separation as areas but that's the best you could get. Another possibility is to split into several applications. Usually that's what I prefer instead of using areas.

Comment: By several applications...you mean like having more than one mvc 3 project file in the solution?

Comment: @TheMentor, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Yes i tried this. I then added reference to my primary mvc 3 project and I could set up simple ActionLink to this second website....the problem that I could not resolve was that this seperate website required diffrent port.

Comment: @TheMentor, when you deploy them in IIS all sites will run on the same port 80.

Comment: I still have one question...when you develop in VS such a project with multiply mvc 3 sites. You then just place actionlinks that connect diffrent sites...test each seperate site independently let say by setting them as startup project and running them...and then see if all fits together when you deploy all sites